# Is my version of the strncmp c function correct?

Tags: c, strncmp

I am trying to write my version of the function `strncmp` that already exists in the C language. Below is the solution I have found; I have tested it with a handful of cases and compared the results with the original `strncmp` C function and I have got same results. Please let me know if there are any flaws in my solution, any errors, etc:

```
/*
 *  IT IS ENOUGH TO CHECK IF WE REACHED THE LENGTH OF ONE
 *  OF THE STRINGS! :)
 */
int my_strncmp(char *s1, char *s2, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int    i;

    i = 0;
    while ((s1[i] == s2[i]) && (s1[i] != 0) && (i < n))
        i++;
    return (s1[i] - s2[i]);
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = "Hello";
    char *barrier = "XXXXXX";
    char *str2 = "Hellz";
    int  n = -1;
    int  max_len = 0;
    int  res;

    max_len = strlen(str1);
    if (strlen(str1) < strlen(str2))
        max_len = strlen(str2);

    // making sure that n is tested way beyond the strlen of strings
    max_len += 2;

    while (n < max_len)
    {
        res = strncmp(str1, str2, n);
        printf("   strncmp(\"%s\",\"%s\", %d) = %d\n", \
            str1, str2, n, res);
        res = my_strncmp(str1, str2, n);
        printf("my_strncmp(\"%s\",\"%s\", %d) = %d\n\n", \
            str1, str2, n, res);
        n++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Hint: IMO you should never address `s1[n]` or `s2[n]`, but your code can do so...

Comment: In multiple places actually https://godbolt.org/z/dnYEz14bY

Comment: Not an error, but... 'Declaring' and then 'Initialising' the value of `i` is a practice should be curbed. There is no reason, especially here, to not use `unsigned i = 0;` Uninitialised variables are a cause of too many SO questions. In fact, simplifying the loop conditional (Credit @JonSkeet) and adding an `if( ... ) return x - y;` would mean `i` could be scoped to only a `for()` loop. (Need a `return 0;` at the bottom, too. Some don't like that sort of coding.)

Comment: ... (more on using simpler `for()` loop & its conditional, with a body of `if(...)` You may next want to implement `strnicmp()` (same idea, but case insensitive). If you redo this version, coding its case insensitive cousin will be much, much simpler (and "consistent").

Comment: @teapot418 I have just tried to replicate your test on my machine and here I got 0 as return from the main? Maybe the OS counts? I am using Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: Re: "_IT IS ENOUGH TO CHECK IF WE REACHED..._" To check for your self, make a table with columns for "len(str1) : len(str2) : 'n' : returnCode". Put big and small numbers into each column (to make 8 rows of distinct combinations) and then think through what the logic should do, filling the 4th column with "success" or "failed" when you consider your own code... Independence is an attribute worth cultivating.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for the hint... it is indeed interesting, s1[n] and s2[n] can be reached in the test of the while, however, the i < n would not allow the while's condition to turn true and keep looping? But, yes, if s1[n] and/or s2[n] gets evaluated, that's considered a kind of "overflow", maybe? Or, it could lead to a segmentation fault? Thank you for your hint! :)

Comment: `0 < my_strncmp("0", "\x81", 1);` vs `0 > strncmp("0", "\x81", 1);`

Comment: The access of item `[n]` is fishy, but maybe not a bug. In case of two equivalent strings, the `(s1[i] != 0) && (i < n)` condition will eventually fail and break the loop. At which point `i == n`. But since arrays are zero-indexed, this leads to `s1[i] - s2[i]` comparing the null terminators. Which are always equivalent. Some "smart" people like to do stuff like that undocumented, so you can never tell if it is intentional or accidental.

Comment: @Lundin: "The access of item [n] is fishy, but maybe not a bug." It feels like a bug to me. It feels like it should be entirely valid for code to crash due to invalid access if you've said "only compare indexes 0 to n-1 inclusive" and you actually perform a comparison using index n. From https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/, one of the termination conditions is "or until num characters match in both strings". Continuing to access other indexes after that is a bug, surely.

Comment: @JonSkeet The thing is: `n` in this context is at most the string length and not the size of the entire array, which would be 1 byte larger. So it is entirely valid to access item `[n]` because it should either be the null terminator or a part of the string, in case `n` is shorter than the string length. It is fishy for sure to compare the null terminators, and badly written code as well, but valid and well-defined C.

Comment: Although `s1[i] - s2[i]` subtracts the value of the two null terminators from each other if the strings are equal. But otherwise uses one operand which is a null terminator and another which is is a value from the longer string. This means that the longer string may compare < -1 or >1 depending on which parameter that was the longer one. That could be said to be an algorithm bug if `"abc"` should always be < than `"abcd"`. But it is not an array out of bounds bug.

Comment: @Lundin: It still seems entirely wrong to me - and it *does* violate the condition of "it should terminate after num characters match in both strings". I see your point about "well it's guaranteed that there's an extra accessible value" but it still looks like it's violating the contract by performing more comparisons than it should.

Answer (score 3):

1. The type of the parameter `n` and of the counter `i` should be `size_t`, not `unsigned int`.
2. The type of the first two parameters should be `const char *`.
3. Although the strings are passed as pointers to `char` (with `const`), the characters should be interpreted as if they had the type `unsigned char`, per C 2018 7.24.1 3.
4. `s1` and `s2` should never be accessed beyond `n` characters, but the code tests `i < n` last, after using `s1[i]` and `s2[i]`, instead of before using them.
5. The code also accesses `s1[i]` and `s2[i]` in the `return` statement even if the loop terminated because `i` reached `n`. Besides causing the routine to access the arrays out of bounds, this also means the return value is very likely to be wrong, as it should be zero but instead will be based on evaluations of the incorrectly accessed `s1[i]` and `s2[i]`.

More theoretically:

6. It is conceivable `char` and `unsigned char` are the same width as `int` and therefore `s1[i] - s2[i]` can overflow or wrap. Instead, the values should be compared and used to select a positive, zero, or negative return value.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest implementation is:

```
int my_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
{
    if (n)
    {
        do 
        {
            unsigned char a = *s1++, b = *s2++;

            if (a != b)
            {
                return a < b ? -1 : +1;
            }

            if (!a)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            
        } while (--n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But this will be very slow with long strings compared to an optimized implementation.

It's very important to use `unsigned char` for comparing. Without `unsigned`:

```
/*unsigned*/ char a = *s1++, b = *s2++;
```

the result will be wrong. (if use `a - b` as return);

Example:

```
s1 = "" and s2 = "\xff";
```

with

```
char a = *s1++, b = *s2++;
```

`b` will `0xff` and will be **signed** extended to `0xffffffff` in the expression `(a - b)` as result will be `0 - 0xffffffff == 1`, bit with:

```
unsigned char a = *s1++, b = *s2++;
```

the result will be `0 - 0xff == 0xFFFFFF01` (negative).

Simple test:

```
void test()
{
    char a=0, b=0;
    do 
    {
        do 
        {
            int i = my_strncmp(&a, &b, 1);
            int j = strncmp(&a, &b, 1);

            if ((i ^ j) & 0x80000000)
            {
                __debugbreak();
            }
             
        } while (--b);
    } while (--a);
}
```

Comment: The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined however. `0xff` might fit just fine in a `char` as the positive value 255. So your examples using a `char` type with range  -128 to +127 are only applicable on such systems. Additionally, there's the pre-C23 madness allowing different signedness formats than two's complement.

Comment: @Lundin -  *0xff might fit* - here task not in fit but in sign extended or zero exteded, in expression `return (s1[i] - s2[i]);`. if we use `signed char` - the negative values 0x80-0xFF will be **signed** extended to `0xFFFFFF80 - 0xFFFFFFFF` and when compare with 0 say - result will be from `0x80` to `0x01` (wrong, positive). in case zero extended (if use unsigned char)  result will be from 0xFFFFFF80 to 0xFFFFFF01 (correct, negative)

Comment: Why the `if` and `do … while` loop rather than a plain ʼwhileʼ loop?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but why not ? Optimization anyway transform while () {} loop to if () { do {} while () }. Yes possible while here too and code became bit smaller in src and bit worse without optimization ( additional unconditional jump in the end of loop) . Optimized code will be equal. This is simply my private style use in most case do {} while(); but agree that here plain while looking better from src view point